# Path.reset vs Path.rewind

Tags: android, reset, graphicspath

In android what is the difference between `path.reset()` and `path.rewind()` ?

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#rewind%28%29) say that

> public void reset ()
>
> Clear any lines and curves from the path, making it empty. This does
>   NOT change the fill-type setting.
>
> public void rewind ()
>
> Rewinds the path: clears any lines and curves from the path but keeps
>   the internal data structure for faster reuse.

but what does that really mean ?

when should either one be used ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Path.reset => Your Path is reseter. Returns to create one: new Path()

Path.rewind => Just empty the contents of the Path, Returns to make .clear() from a list

Comment: Should also mention that `rewind` is only useful if your paths have the same number of points. Otherwise, it is actually more expensive than `reset`

Comment: @smac89 I'm curious, how is rewind more expensive than reset in that case?